# Find number of possible triplets $(a,b,c)$ if $LCM\left(a,b\right)=5^2\times 3^4;LCM\left(b,c\right)=5^3\times 3^4;LCM\left(a,c\right)=5^3\times 3^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Find number of possible triplets $(a,b,c)$ if

$LCM\left(a,b\right)=5^2\times 3^4$

$LCM\left(b,c\right)=5^3\times 3^4$

$LCM\left(a,c\right)=5^3\times 3^4$

**My Attempt**

Since $LCM\left(a,b\right)=5^2\times 3^4$. Power of $5$ in both $a$ and $b$ therefore can never be $3$.
So, power of $5$ in $c$ must be $3$.

But after this I am not able to solve

Comment: Well, so at least one of $a,b$ contains $5^2$ as a factor.  And at least two terms contain $3^4$.  Seems like that should be enough to work with.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to note that you can distribute the $3's$ and the $5's$ separately, and multiply the number of ways to do each.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a 13 year old who loves maths, so i might be wrong, but
First, just like you noticed, the p-adic valuation for c is $\nu_{5}=3$, now, we can notice that between a and b, one of them must be $\nu_{5}=2$, and the other is free to be $\nu_{5}\in\{0,1,2\}$, which gives us $3×2=6$ ways of distributing the power of 5
Now for the power of 3, we take a and b, since their LCM has $3^4$, at least one of them has $\nu_{3}=4$. If it's a, then b has $\nu_{3} \in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Then if b has $\nu_{3}=4$, then c has $\nu_{3}\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, but if b has $\nu_{3}\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, then c must have $\nu_{3}=4$ thus at least two numbers have $\nu_{3}=4$, and the third one has $\nu_{3}\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ thus there are $3×5=15$ ways to rearrange here.
From all of this, we get that there are $6×15=75$ triplets that satisfy this system of equations.